# Knockout Components , the template has already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-components

From [Knockoutjs Docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html) i don't understand this sentence :
**the template has already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.**

```
ko.components.register('my-component', {
viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
        // - 'params' is an object whose key/value pairs are the parameters
        //   passed from the component binding or custom element
        // - 'componentInfo.element' is the element the component is being
        //   injected into. When createViewModel is called, the template has
        //   already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.

        // Return the desired view model instance, e.g.:
        return new MyViewModel(params);
    }
},
template: ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say the template for "my-component" is (regardless of how it's defined)

```
<span class="foo" data-bind="text: 'foo'"></span>
```

---

The sentence "the template has already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound" describes the state of the DOM for a given component.  (A.K.A. `componentInfo.element` in the context of the `createViewModel` function)

Through the process of binding the component, the DOM for the component looks like this:

**Before the template has been injected into the component:**

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

**After the template has been injected into the component, but before binding happens:** (this is the state of the DOM when `createViewModel` is called, hence the comment)

```
<my-component>
    <span class="foo" data-bind="text: 'foo'">
    </span>
</my-component>
```

**After binding happens:** (this can only happen after `creteViewModel` has returned the ViewModel)

```
<my-component>
    <span class="foo" data-bind="text: 'foo'">
         foo
    </span>
</my-component>
```

The span only has text in the last step because bindings have now been applied, and the `text` binding has added text to the component.

---

The comment is meant to indicate that the DOM is in the second state, which means you could manipulate the DOM elements of the Component from the `createViewModel` function, if you wanted, though the KO documentation recommends against it:

> Note that, typically, it’s best to perform direct DOM manipulation only through custom bindings rather than acting on componentInfo.element from inside createViewModel

Answer (score 1):

> new MyViewModel(params);

`MyViewModel` is the desired view model instance. This is a factory design patter used in knockout.

If you want to run any setup logic on the associated element before it is bound to the viewmodel, or use arbitrary logic to decide which viewmodel class to instantiate: Here comes the role of  `factory function` .

The view modal will be chosen based on your logic on run time.

---

> the template has already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.

Once you return your desired view modal then it will bound to your `ko.components`.